# Are there seeds that should be avoided when using Random?

Tags: .net, random

When using System.Random in .NET and supplying it with a seed, are there some seeds that should be avoided? I am asking because I like to inject a known seed when running simulation-like computations, so that I can replicate results later if needed. However, the function underlying a random number generator is periodical, the period depending on the seed, so I would like to know if there are caveats with the specific System.Random implementation, and, as a bonus, if anyone knows what function it uses behind the covers.

Note: I am aware that System.Random is not a high-quality RNG, and that I should be using something else for serious simulation. This question is strictly about System.Random and its implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt that there is any general rule to which seeds will give a shorter period than others.  Larger numbers aren't going to guarantee a longer period, and numbers like 0 won't necessarily have a short period.

From the [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The current implementation of the Random class is based on Donald E. Knuth's subtractive random number generator algorithm. For more information, see D. E. Knuth. "The Art of Computer Programming, volume 2: Seminumerical Algorithms". Addison-Wesley, Reading, MA, second edition, 1981.

There's also a [Microsoft Connect thread](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/634761/system-random-serious-bug) about a bug in the implementation of the algorithm.  Apparently there is a typo in the .NET code.  One of the .NET software engineers commented:

> Indeed, [there is] a genuine problem with the Random implementation.
>
> We have discussed it within the team and with some of our partners and concluded that we unfortunately cannot fix the problem right now. The reason is that some applications rely on the fact that when initialised with the same seed, the generator produces the same pseudo random sequence. Even if the change is for the better, it will break the applications that made this assumption once they have migrated to the “fixed” version.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of points -

1. I don't think the periodicity of well known PRNGs depend on seed. I am sure the issue would have been addressed during implementation
2. However poor seeding can result in long sequence of seemingly non-random values, see [Disadvantages of Mersenne Twister](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister#Disadvantages)
3. The above point is important because the .NET implementation can change in future